# shell script for curl command with variable in --data-binary

Tags: python, shell, variables, curl

for day now i am trying to get this shell script line of code done that should just have a parameter with a variable. I have tried:

```
file=~/myname-"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`".abc
file_at=`(printf '"@';printf ${file};printf '"')`
curl -H "Content-Type: application/timestamp-query" --data-binary $file_at https://someserver.com --output myname-"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`".def
```

The response is wrong which can be verified by another call and changing the `$file_at` to a filename `'@filename.def'` will yield a correct verification.

So the question is just, how can the --data-binary argument be a variable?
I have tried everything I could find on SO but without any success.
Alternatively a python script with `requests` or `httpx` would be fine.

Kind regards

Comment: All you need to prepend the `@` is a simple variable expansion `--data-binary "@$file"`

Comment: oh thx, one more case of sitting for too long alone on the computer :)
if you want me to vote then you can write an answer or I answer myself.